# SQL. How to seperate string ending and get sum values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two databases. One is for Navision, other for WMS. I need to get percent of Finished items / Planned items. The problem is that there are no key for those DBs. I'am trying to join DBs tables with same value column (ex.: `Prod_ Order_No (PK, varchar(20), not null)` and `production_order_no(varchar(255,null)`.

Anyway I got values only from one DB. Second DB values almost always are `NULL`.
But it isn't true...

There is my SQL query code:

```
SELECT      i.[code], i.[description],
            p.[quantity],
            uom.code [uom],
            uom.[quantity_per_base_unit_of_measure] [uom_qty],
            p.[quantity]*uom.[quantity_per_base_unit_of_measure]  total,
            wc.code,
            pol."Finished Qty_ (Base)", 
            p.[date_created]
FROM [TWMS].[dbo].[package] p


LEFT JOIN [TWMS].[dbo].[item] i                     ON p.[item_id]          =   i.id
LEFT JOIN [TWMS].[dbo].[item_unit_of_measure] uom       ON p.[uom_id]           =   uom.id 
LEFT JOIN [TWMS].[dbo].[work_center] wc             on p.[work_center_id]   =   wc.id
FULL JOIN [Artilux].[dbo].[Trivilita UAB$Prod_ Order Line] pol on p.[id] = pol.[Line No_] 
WHERE  p.[date_created] >= '2015-07-31' 
AND p.[date_created] <= '2015-08-01' 
AND wc.[code] = 'SF01'
AND wc.[code] not like '%/%'
ORDER BY p.[date_created]
```

This is what i get:

```
SOF01004/1  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:00:03.863
SOF01004/1  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:00:48.673
SOF01004/1  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:05:08.070
SOF01004/3  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:09:11.440
SOF01004/3  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:09:14.653
SOF01004/1  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:24:13.927
SOF01004/2  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:24:17.810
SOF01004/2  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:24:20.890
SOF01004/2  SOFA HAVANA OC+H+2,5+D (left)Joise Beige/Brown  1.00    VNT 1.00    1.0000  SF01    NULL    2015-07-31 06:24:24.093
```

1 Problem. Eight column shouldn't be NULL.. Maybe my join is wrong?

2 Problem. First column is item code, but SOF01004/1 and SOF01004/3 and etc is 1 item from three pieces. So i need to drop all /1, /2, /3 and get only SOF01004 + sum of quantity (where FULL SOF01004 item equals to the MIN part. Something like that: there are `sum(SOF01004/1) = 3`, `sum(SOF01004/2) = 2`, `sum(SOF01004/3) = 10`, so count of item SOF01004 should be 2. Because there are 2 full items from theese pieces.

3 Problem. I need to get percentage of `SUM(pol."(Finished Qty (Base)") / SUM(p.[quantity])) * 100` but the problem is that one column is from one DB and second is from other.. :/

ASK ME FOR MORE INFORMATION. I WILL EDIT MY POST. AND OF COURSE SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH.

Comment: Are you sure about that 8th column name?   Can you post a screenshot of it?   What if you try referencing it like this?:    pol.[Finished Qty_ (Base)],

Comment: @TabAlleman yeah im sure, because ms sql server can understand both "" and [], anyway changing "" to [] doesnt change anything, still NULL

Comment: @TabAlleman what screenshot you want to see exactly?

Comment: If you change your SELECT clause to include pol.*, do you see any data in any of the columns for pol?

Answer (score 0):

For the problem 2:

If the quantity for an item (e.g. SOF01004/1) is 0, does it still have a row in package or can it be missing totally?

If it always exists, I would do something like this:

```
select 
    case when POS > 0 then left(code, POS-1) else code end as code,
    description,
    min(quantity) 
from (
    SELECT
        i.code, 
        patindex('%/[0-9]', i.code) as POS,
        i.description,
        sum(p.quantity),
    ...
    group by i.code, i.description ...
) X
group by
    case when POS > 0 then left(code, POS-1) else code end as code,
    description,
    ....
```

Here the patindex assumes the end is always / + 1 number. If it can be more digits, adding more patindex fields might be the best option. If there is never / in the code itself, using charindex works too.

If the rows can be missing from the database totally and should be then treated as zeros, I would then create a table looking something like this:

```
SOF01004/1    SOF01004
SOF01004/2    SOF01004
SOF01004/3    SOF01004
```

Then you could use this table for the fetch and outer join the package table with this to get the shorter code, and use isnull(quantity,0) to get the missing quantities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. theese rows always exist if item is made from 3 pieces. I will try your code.

Comment: Well I am bad at sql, i can't integrate your code to my existing code :|

Comment: @Rokas Start adding it one by one, try to add the sum of quantities to see that you'll get the total for the item with /x values, then the patindex should return you the place where / starts, then you can add the case clause to get the select to see that you have the items without the ending and then you can add the min -function to get the only minimum  values.

Comment: Look 

10 GU0268402/1
10 GU0268402/1
10 GU0268402/1
10 GU0268402/1
10 GU0268402/1
10 GU0268402/1
10 GU0268402/1
10 GU0280250/1
10 GU0280250/1
10 GU0280250/1
10 GU0280250/1

The first column is POS and second is i.code.
I need that POS return values like GU0280250

Comment: @Rokas Yes that looks ok, that's why there was the case clause, I made it for case that / doesn't exist, but for this left(code, 9) should show the correct code, what the pos - 1 does as the second parameter.